# ARM to Bicep conversion problem given that no module in Bicep

Tags: azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy 1es hosted pool in azure , in ARM they use Microsoft.CloudTest/images. This module is not available on Bicep . This deployment asks to register below namespace
az provider register --namespace "Microsoft.CloudTest". When I try to convert this ARM into Bicep resource type I see an error saying it is not available.  (Microsoft.CloudTest/images@2020-05-07).
Is every ARM resource has equalent  BICEP.

is there a Microsoft.CloudTest/images in Bicep , Its not there in Microsoft documentation. Should it be implemented in ARM if there is no module in Bicep for this ?

Comment: if you can do it with arm you can do it with bicep. bicep is a DSL for ARM deployment. Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/images?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) there is no api-version 2020-05-07 which is probably the issue. update the arm with a different version and try again => there is a 2020-12-01 version so that would be the closest.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I tried registering the provider using `az provider register --namespace "Microsoft.CloudTest"` and was able to register successfully.

Once it is done, I created a sample ARM template code with the registered provider and tried to decompile it into bicep using
`az bicep decompile --file cloud.json --force`.

In the output, it showed no errors but given provider `Microsoft.CloudTest/images@2020-05-07` doesn't have types available is shown as below.

[image]

Then after a workaround, I got to know that cloud images are similar to the compute images provider which is available in ARM templates
(Eg: Bicep).

Refer [`Microsoft.Compute/images`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/images?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) for the above related information.

Below is the sample `Json` template with the`Compute/images` provider:

```bash
{
   "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
   "resources":[
   {
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/images",
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "name": "myImage",
    "location": "global",
    "properties": {
        "storageProfile": {
            "osDisk": {
                "osType": "Windows",
                "osState": "Generalized"
            }
        }
    }
   }
   ]
}
```

*And the decompilation is successfully done without any errors.*

[image]